# Hide plot axis but show labels

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am trying to create a plot with PyQtGraph in PyQt5 but struggling with the axis configuration. I want to hide the axis, ticks and values but keep the label that I will change dynamically. Problem I am having is when I hide the axis the label gets hidden as well. Is there a way to hide the axis line and keep the label?

So far I have only managed to hide the ticks and values, but not the axis itself. Here is the code I've used to configure the axis.

```py
desc = self.descriptors[i]
self.plots[i].showAxis('right')
self.plots[i].getAxis('right').enableAutoSIPrefix(enable=False)
self.plots[i].getAxis('right').setLabel(text=desc, units=None)
self.plots[i].getAxis('right').setStyle(tickLength=0, showValues=False)
```

This is what I have so far.
[image: What I have]

And this is what I'm trying to achieve. The vertical axis are missing but the values are still there.
[image: What I have]

Answer (score 0):

A hack is to set the pen drawing the axis and tick lines to the same color as the background. There may be a simpler way to set the pen kwarg but a very simple subclass of axisitem will do the trick.

```
class MyStringAxis(pg.AxisItem):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pg.AxisItem.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then set the axisitem on your plot.

```
plot.setAxisItems(axisItems={'left': MyStringAxis(orientation='left', pen=(0, 0, 0, 
0))})
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the grid and axis lines share the same pen, so using a NoPen Qt.PenStyle, or setting the colour to the background, will also remove the grid lines.  However, we can exploit the fact that the alpha value for the pen is replaced when drawing the grid lines.  Set the axis item pen to use the default colour (foreground), but with a zero alpha value:

```
axis_pen = pyqtgraph.mkPen(pyqtgraph.getConfigOption('foreground') + (0, ))
...
self.plots[i].getAxis('right').setPen(axis_pen)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/graphicsItems/plotitem.html

In the documentation. PlotItem -> showAxes

```
pi = self.tab.addPlot(...)
pi.showAxes(False, False)
```

This will disable all axes and ticks.